# Exactly when do the ARMED Speed Brakes extend after landing a B737-800?

Tags: landing, boeing-737, airbrakes

When do the armed speed brakes of a B737-800 extend after landing?

Is it when the main gear makes contact with the ground, or must the nose gear also be on the ground?

Answer (score 6):

The system will extend the **flight** spoilers when any strut (either main gear or the nosewheel) compresses; the **ground** spoilers deploy after the right main gear strut compresses. Everything will deploy even if the nosewheel is held off the runway, although that's not a recommended landing technique.

Additionally, other conditions are required:

- the system is armed (speed brake lever in the ARMED detent, and the SPEEDBRAKE ARMED light illuminated)
- radio altitude below 10 feet
- both throttles at idle

Additionally, the system will deploy the spoilers *without* detecting strut compression if it senses main gear wheels spinning up to 60+ knots (presumably both sides, but the manual I'm looking at isn't clear on that).

Source: an airline manual that isn't public domain, so no link or screenshot - sorry.